# ScreenShare: command line and observe only

Tags: mac-osx, terminal, osx-snow-leopard, screen-sharing

I have a wide TV screen that is attached to a Mac Mini. I am able to use this screen as a second screen using an application like ScreenRecycler. However, Sometimes I want to demonstrate what I am doing on my box on this TV screen. As this TV is attached to a Mac Mini, I want to have a screen sharing done reversed. As I know screen share can be done in observe mode and full screen, this would be more than sufficient. Because it would be pretty useless to run it continuously, I want it on demand. For this, I want to use SSH.

So the only thing I would like to know is, how do I start screen sharing in from a Terminal Session. On Windows, I could start an application by using "start notepad.exe", I am looking for something similar. Eventually, I want to make this work on other boxes too.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a script can be done by using "open". As Screen Share does not really have a suitable manual around to play with, I can't find a default setting that makes it go full-screen.

I use open vnc://remote-ip to make this work.

Comment: the easier way is to use iChat auto-accept scripts.